# Automapper projection returns empty list when query is not empty

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm implementing automapper for view models in a project and I'm just getting started with it.  A hurdle I'm finding myself up against is a type of behavior I'm not familiar with in Automapper.  I've been using automapper on a couple projects now and I haven't come across this issue before.

Basically in code this is what's happening:

```
var q = dbContext.Orders.Where(x => x.Name == 'name');
var l = q.ToList(); // count == 10
var shared = q.ProjectTo<OrderSharedModel>().ToList(); // count == 0
```

I figured out that when mapping a property that's null, it doesn't map anymore and it's like it just skips the mapping of that entity entirely.

For example:

```
class Order {
  public int OrderId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int? OrderTypeId { get; set; }
  public virtual OrderType { get; set; }
}

class OrderSharedModel {
  public int OrderId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public OrderTypeSharedModel OrderType { get; set; }
}
```

If OrderType is null in `Order` then it will cause `ProjectTo<OrderSharedModel>().ToList()` to return an empty list.  If I commented out `OrderType` in the shared model, `ProjectTo<OrderSharedModel>().ToList()` will return the full list.  This is weird to me.

Why would `ProjectTo<OrderSharedModel>().ToList()` return an empty list if the original query before ProjectTo() is not empty?  Why won't automapper map a null property as null rather than skip the mapping entirely and return an empty list?

--UPDATE--

However if I use the other way mapping:

```
var l = q.ToList();
var sm = Mapper.Map<List<Order>, List<OrderSharedModel>>(l);
```

It works great.  I'm doing this for now until I find exactly why the queryable extension breaks.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: Also, check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu - I'm going to try and see if I can't find what's wrong by checking the execution plan.

Comment: I just had this error too. silently failing and just returning 0 results suddenly. wshat was the conclusion?

Comment: @Worthy7 - it appears upgrading to version 9 works.  I haven't verified though.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Just encountered the same issue, an inner property of the dto was null and for some reason it was not in the result list. I upgraded from AutoMapper 8.1 to 9.0 and it works fine now.

Comment: I've been working on the latest for a while, I haven't come across this issue again cheers!